# Add a prefix to each type in a string union type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a type from a union type where each element of the union will be transformed according to a pattern? I just need to put a prefix:

```
type EventNames = 'DragStart' | 'Drag' | 'DragStop'
type HandlerNames = Prefix<'on', EventNames> // 'onDragStart' | 'onDrag' | 'onDragStop'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Since [TypesScript 4.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html) you can use a [Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) in combination with a [Template Literal Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) like so:

```
type EventNames = "DragStart" | "Drag" | "DragStop";

type Prefix<K> = K extends string ? `on${K}` : K;
// --> "onDragStart" | "onDrag" | "onDragStop"

const myEvent: Prefix<EventNames> = "onDrag";
```

Or directly define the generic to extend `string` in order to pass a prefix:

```
type EventNames = "DragStart" | "Drag" | "DragStop";

type Prefix<Prefix extends string, T extends string> = `${Prefix}${T}`;
const myEvent: Prefix<"on", EventNames> = "onDrag";
```

Comment: That's neat! Thank you, I didn't know TS allowed string concat like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
type Prefix<P extends string, S extends string> = `${P}${S}`

type EventNames = 'DragStart' | 'Drag' | 'DragStop'
type HandlerNames = Prefix<'on', EventNames> // 'onDragStart' | 'onDrag' | 'onDragStop'

const handler1: HandlerNames = 'onDrag';
const handler2: HandlerNames = 'onDraggo'; // error!
```

See stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-98syrf?file=index.ts